# Specifying accuracy in GPX or KML

Tags: android, kml, gpx

I am developing an Android application and would like to play a recorded track in DDMS tool. Besides latitude and longitude, my recorded data has horizontal accuracy which I'd like to pass to Android phone simulator.

Is there a way to specify accuracy in GPX or KML formats?

Comment: were u able to find a solution to this one?

Answer (score 2):

In neither of those specs is a named element for accuracy. Both however allow for extended data which where you can put whatever you want.

In GPX it's called 'extensions' See http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/#type_extensionsType
In Kml it's called 'ExtendedData' See http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#placemark

Answer (score 1):

As Eddy noted, there are no tags for accuracy.

But, GPX have something similar -- tags for dilution of precision (hdop, vdop, pdop) for every track point, waypoint or route point. Those are not exactly the same as "accuracy", but it can be used as such. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_of_precision_%28GPS%29) for more.